# What is the proper way to get the mouse position in a React Component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that renders a canvas element.  I have an `onMouseMove` handler, but when I move my mouse towards the top of the element `event.clientY` prints 86.  Why not 0?  Is there an synthetic event property that will give me the point relative to the element's coordinate system and not the windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use targets `offsetTop` to get relative position by subtracting from `clientY` like

```
event.clientY - event.target.offsetTop
```

You can see the example

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div>Top Component</div>
        <div className="main" onMouseMove={(e) => console.log(e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop)}>Main Component</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
div{
  min-height: 50px;
}

div.main{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: so you have to go through the synthetic event to the native event just to get the actual coordinate in the element's coordinate system?

Comment: Not sure of this. But we don't have any reference for relative offset through synthetic events as you see in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events). So took native event for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

```
event.clientY
```

Will return the position relative to the window, not the parent.

Try doing the following

```
event.pageY - event.target.offsetTop
```